# StringBuilder: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, websphere, stringbuilder, websphere-7

We're experiencing a strange issue with WebSphere 7/ IBM JDK 6, where one of the nodes has some initialization issue.

We have some code which calls InitialContext.lookup and on this node we're getting sometimes the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
         at java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:666)
         at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:207)
         at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLContext(NamingManager.java:646)
         at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:422)
         at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
         [...]
```

We had a look at the  source code of javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLContext:

```
public static Context getURLContext(String schema, Hashtable<?, ?> envmt)
        throws NamingException {

    if (null == schema || 0 == schema.length() || null == envmt) {
        return null;
    }

    // obtain pkg prefixes from hashtable
    String pkgPrefixes[] = EnvironmentReader
            .getFactoryNamesFromEnvironmentAndProviderResource(envmt, null,
                    Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES);

    for (String element : pkgPrefixes) {
        // create factory instance
        ObjectFactory factory;
        String clsName = element + "." //$NON-NLS-1$
                + schema + "." //$NON-NLS-1$
                + schema + "URLContextFactory"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    [...]
```

Line 646 is the enhanced for-loop, but the next statement is a String concatenation and is probably replaced with a StringBuilder by the compiler.

We did some quick unit tests on StringBuilder but couldn't provoke an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

How can an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException be thrown here and how can we avoid it?

**Edit**:

We are using the following java version:

```
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6460sr9fp2ifix-20110913_02(SR9 FP2+IV03622+IZ99243))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux amd64-64 jvmxa6460sr9-20110912_90359 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20110912_090359
JIT  - r9_20101028_17488ifx31
GC   - 20101027_AA)
JCL  - 20110727_04
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see what actually happens there?

Comment: Too late, the problematic node as already been restarted. :-/

Comment: Don't you have a test system? ;-| Could you additionally post the code of the for-loop you've mentioned?

Comment: It happened on the test system. ;-) But I'm not sure how easy it is to get one of the nodes in that state again on purpose.

Comment: @user714965 see my updated quesion

Comment: @Udo Held: Thanks for the edit, I missed that.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug of the JIT compiler of the IBM JVM. The workaround seems to be the exclusion of `getChars` from the JIT compilation:

```
-Xjit:exclude={ProgramClass.callStringGetChars*}
```

See [IZ78413: JIT-COMPILED STRING.GETCHARS THROWS UNEXPECTED ARRAYINDEXOUTOFBO UNDSEXCEPTION](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ78413) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I'll double check which version we have.

Comment: The issue says: "This defect will be fixed in:
6.0.0 SR9
.
The JIT compiler has been updated to correct its algorithms.
.
To obtain the fix:
Install build 20100622 or later"

So we should have this fix (see my edited question, which mentions the java version we use)

Comment: I still don't know why the version we're using doesn't contain the fix, but I guess this answer goes in the right direction, so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The code above seems to return `null` if you pass a null environment hashtable.

This makes me wonder if you are instantiating InitialContext with an argument of some sort.

If the code above is indeed the source, passing a null environment hashtable will short-circuit getURLContext() to return `null` prior to the string concatenation loop.

Can you try `new InitialContext()` or `new InitialContext(null)` if you do not need to specify JNDI environment vars (e.g. use default JNDI env)?

Comment: We're using the no-argument constructor. If envmt were null, this wouldn't match the stack trace, I think.